# How can I convert a raw PCM stream to an opus or wav stream in Node JS for a Discord bot?

Tags: node.js, audio, discord.js, pcm, opus

### Background:

I am creating a personal music bot for [Discord](https://discord.com/), mainly using [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/), and one of the features I'd like to add is having the bot play audio directly from [Voicemeeter](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/). This solution is optimal because bots are able to stream in much better quality than Discord users are, and they are able to play stereo sound instead of mono, and I can choose what sources are streamed with Voicemeeter.

Voicemeeter comes with a feature called VBAN which allows you to send audio data over your network using the [VBAN protocol](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/VBANProtocol_Specifications.pdf) to another computer running a VBAN receiver.

Jacob Bower made a [VBAN receiver script](https://github.com/JMJBower/node-VBAN) in Node JS that takes the raw PCM audio data and plays it through your speakers using node-speaker.

### Problem:

Using Jacob's script, if you try to pipe the PCM audio directly into the Discord bot, it gives the error "Error [VOICE_PLAY_INTERFACE_BAD_TYPE]: Unknown stream type." I believe this is because the PCM audio received from the script is contained in a Buffer, which the discord bot cannot play natively. I need to find a way to get that PCM audio in a readable format for the discord bot to play. (Readable formats I believe include opus and wav, (and possibly other streaming formats that aren't PCM))

### What I have tried:

- As stated above, I directly piped the PCM audio buffers into the bot, and it gives that error.
- I attempted putting the buffers into a PassThrough Stream, and piping that stream into the bot.
  This is met with no errors in console, the bot joining the voice channel like it should, and emitting no sound. I think this is because discord.js does not support playing raw PCM audio which I learned after the fact.
- **[The Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/voice/understanding-voice.html#understanding-voice) mentions that PCM needs to be encoded with opus to be able to play over discord.** So I tried using the [opus encoder built into discord.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@discordjs/opus). First I tried encoding each PCM buffer and writing that into a PassThrough stream.

```
const { OpusEncoder } = require('@discordjs/opus');
const { PassThrough } = require('stream');
const EncodedStream = new PassThrough();
const encoder = new OpusEncoder(48000, 2); //48000 hz, 2 channels

. . .

if (data.header.sp == 0) { //This code executes each time there is a new frame sent from VBAN
     EncodedStream.write(encoder.encode(data.audio));
}

. . .

connection.play(EncodedStream); //Connection is just the Bot being inside a voice channel.
```

That was met with the error `"Cannot create a Buffer larger than 0xffffffff bytes."` I'm not sure why that error came up, because running Buffer.byteLength on each of the buffers yielded 1024.

- I then moved on to trying to use [prism-media](https://amishshah.github.io/prism-media/) to encode the stream where found more errors and more of the bot remaining silent.
- I installed some npm modules that claimed they could convert streams to AudioBuffers, and another module that would convert the PCM AudioBuffer to a usable wav format, but I found more errors there too.

---

I am at my wits end right now trying to solve this problem, and any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Discord side, but what sort of container is expected?  WebM?